# How to create an Array of this class that implements 3 interfaces?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, polymorphism, hierarchy

I am practicing polimorfism ,hierarchy and interfaces, so I decide to create a class "Duck", this class can Walk, Swim and Fly, also I have created a class eagle  and flyer fish.

Duck Implements 3 Interfaces : Aquatic, Terrestrial and Aerial
Eagle Implements 2 Interfaces : Aerial and Terrestrial
Flyer Fish Implements 2 Interfaces : Aerialand Aquatic

Those interfaces  extends from Animal that has only one method:

```
public void eat();
```

Then I decide to create an Array and trigger their respective actions:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
FlyerFish ff = new FlyerFish();
Eagle eg = new Eagle();
Duck dk= new Duck();
animals.add(ff);
animals.add(eg);
animals.add(dk);

foreach(Animal animal : animals){
        if(animal instanceof Acuatico) {
            ((Acuatico) animal).swim();
        }
        if(animal instanceof Terrestre) {
            ((Terrestre) animal).walk();
        }
        if(animal instanceof Aereo) {
            ((Aereo) animal).fly();
        }
}
```

I feel all those casts are unnecessary or can be avoided.

Comment: Well, do _all_ animals in the array implement all of those interfaces? Probably not, at least not if you want to have `Duck`, `Eagle` and `FlyerFish` all in the same array. Hence you need to check what they actually implement to be able to call those methods. What you probably would want to do is have a generic `move()` method which has different implementations for swimming, walking and flying.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel all those casts are unnecessary or can be avoided.

They are not. All you know about `animal` is that it is of type `Animal`, which has the `eat` method. Therefore you can easily call `animal.eat()` without casting. However, not all `Animal`s have the `swim()` method, or `walk()`, or `fly()`. That is why you have to check for each type and cast before calling that method.